# Load CARLA Blueprint in Unreal Engine

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, carla

I want to load a blueprint from the CARLA Simulator 0.9.10.1 to check some dimensions of a vehicle in a coordinate system (Lincoln MKZ 2017) in the Unreal Engine Editor.

I found the folder in CARLA that contains the .uexp and .uasset files. I put the folder into a new project folder in the Unreal Engine Editor and strangely no files are shown except some textures and a prop. If I try to interact with those files the editor immediately crashes. It happens in UE 4.26.2 and UE 5.2.1. The crash report doesnt state anything helpful. Can someone help or suggest another tactic do achieve my goal?

Thank you!